# Development SMTP server to send emails to single email address

Tags: asp.net, email, smtp

My asp.net web application sends notification to different users.
The development team with 8 members working on this project and they have real copy of database which contains some real users.

I want to setup a local SMTP server (myemailserver.mycompany.com) which I can configure in all development environment, just add smtp server IP in all web.configs.

The machine myemailserver.mycompany.com is in my domain and all developers machine are also in same domain.

After that email sent from code to **any email address** should go to single email say test@myemailserver.mycompany.com

How can I do this.

Comment: All this I need to do on Windows server 2008. I have already install smtp .

Comment: I don't understand your question what you want to do? If it is working fine then what you want to achieve?

Comment: currently I using real smtp server and as a result real user receive email whenever developer tests something.

The mail goes to actual client email from developer by mistake, i want to avoid this.

Comment: see my answer I think smtp4dev is a best which you could get

Answer (score 1):

Try smtp4dev a development smtp server easy to configure and feature enrich.

http://smtp4dev.codeplex.com/

Comment: It is good tool indeed if I have a simple mail send code. But it crashes when you have  SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

Comment: I think you can do it via manually in web.config. In production web.config you can make true while in local for dev you can make it false very easy work arround